# Which bible is the best for the Catholic faith?

Tags: catholicism

I was raised a Catholic and want to return to the church after many years. My question is the Bible I am supposed to read. I have the ESV study Bible  and the NRSV Bible. Which is the best for the catholic faith?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE, and thanks for taking the site tour. See also: [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites). Thanks for asking a question here. As I've indicated above, this question has already been asked and answered, at the link provided. I hope that question and its answers helps! And I do hope you'll stick around and browse some of the other questions and answers.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it in American English, The New American Bible Revised Edition, is the standard Bible for American English per the United States Council of Catholic Bishops.  Other translations that are approved by the USCCB are:

> Books of the New Testament, Alba House
>
> Contemporary English Version - New Testament, First Edition, American
>   Bible Society
>
> Contemporary English Version - Book of Psalms, American Bible Society
>
> Contemporary English Version - Book of Proverbs, American Bible
>   Society
>
> The Grail Psalter (Inclusive Language Version), G.I.A. Publications
>
> New American Bible, Revised Edition (NABRE)
>
> New Revised Standard Version, Catholic Edition, National Council of
>   Churches
>
> The Psalms, Alba House
>
> The Psalms (New International Version) - St. Joseph Catholic Edition,
>   Catholic Book Publishing Company
>
> The Psalms - St. Joseph New Catholic Version, Catholic Book Publishing
>   Company
>
> Revised Psalms of the New American Bible (1991)
>
> So You May Believe, A Translation of the Four Gospels, Alba House
>
> Today's English Version, Second Edition, American Bible Society
>
> Translation for Early Youth, A Translation of the New Testament for
>   Children, Contemporary English Version, American Bible Society

Approval source: [USCCB](http://usccb.org/bible/approved-translations/index.cfm)

For other nations who are English speakers, check with the council of Bishops for that nation.

Which is "best" depends a lot on personal preferences.